# conemu64 terminal color changed to reddish color

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, colors, conemu

In `Conemu64` I was installing updates and pressed `Ctrl` + `C` to cancel the updating of softwares installed suddenly the terminal color is changed to **reddish**.

In order to simulate the above operation we can issue `choco outdated` command in terminal and when its starts listing the *outdated* packages we will press `Ctrl` + `C` and cancel the operation. Then we can see the **reddish** console similar to the below image.

[image: Conemu64 termianl]

How to fix the color issue in Conemu64 terminal?

How can I reset the color to original color?

Answer (score 0):

Close and reopen the tab. That should be enough.

If you need to keep it open, you can try using the ANSI escape code for resetting formatting:

```
Write-Host "`e[0m"
```

Backtick syntax is available only in PowerShell 7+, in earlier versions use `$([char]27)` instead.

Comment: yes I need to keep the shell open and I tried the above command it didn't work. I issued the command `choco outdated` in terminal and halted the process using `Ctrl` + `C` and the terminal turned reddish and pasted `Write-Host "\`e[0m"` but its didn't worked

Comment: You need to be more accurate in that case. In 1st post you mention installing packages, but the screen is from `choco outdated` and also your comment now. Which one did you stop and when? Also please show a screen as to what happens after you paste that command and execute next one.

Comment: I have updated my question and the output after pasting `Write-Host "\`e[0m"` remains the reddish color as provided in the image